# Cannot delete .Trash-503 directory, returns a $RECYCLE.BIN.trashinfo: Input/output error

Tags: disk, partitioning, rm

I cannot delete `.Trash-503` folder via GUI or terminal,
it returns a `$RECYCLE.BIN.trashinfo: Input/output error`

Not even `sudo rm -r` or even a simple `ls` works in that trash directory.

Check terminal output below:

```
subroot@subroot:~$ cd /media/xxxxx/

subroot@subroot:/media/xxxxx$ rm .Trash-503/
rm: cannot remove `.Trash-503/': Is a directory

subroot@subroot:/media/xxxxx$ rm -r .Trash-503/
rm: cannot remove `.Trash-503/info/$RECYCLE.BIN.trashinfo': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove `.Trash-503/info/found.000.trashinfo': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove `.Trash-503/info': Directory not empty

subroot@subroot:/media/xxxxx$ sudo rm -r .Trash-503/
[sudo] password for subroot:
rm: cannot remove `.Trash-503/info/$RECYCLE.BIN.trashinfo': Input/output error
rm: cannot remove `.Trash-503/info/found.000.trashinfo': Input/output error

subroot@subroot:/media/xxxxx$ cd .Trash-503/

subroot@subroot:/media/xxxxx/.Trash-503$ ls
info

subroot@subroot:/media/xxxxx/.Trash-503$ cd info/

subroot@subroot:/media/xxxxx/.Trash-503/info$ ls
ls: cannot access $RECYCLE.BIN.trashinfo: Input/output error
ls: cannot access found.000.trashinfo: Input/output error
found.000.trashinfo  $RECYCLE.BIN.trashinfo

subroot@subroot:/media/xxxxx/.Trash-503/info$
```

What's going on here and how can I delete this folder?

**EDIT**

I tried checking and repairing the partition using gparted only to get this error message:

> ERROR: Filesystem check failed!
>   ERROR: 264 clusters are referenced multiple times.
>   NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
>   The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
>   and will be made to NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.

I don't have windows installed, how can I run `chkdsk /f` from ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

*Input/output  error* means it could be a hardware malfunction or corrupted file system. Most probabily, some of the sectors of your storage device get damaged.
See the following error message, the command fails when trying to delete file *found.000* which is a lost file recovered by a filesystem check utility.

> rm: cannot remove `.Trash-503/info/found.000.trashinfo': Input/output error

First of all **backup all important data** on the partition (if possible whole disk as sector damage may spread over all partition).

## Check file system

`fsck /dev/sdxx` where xx is your target partition. This should fix your current problem.

## format partition

If this problem repeat for other files you better do a **complete format** (not quick format) using a partitioning tool like *gnome-disks*

## dispose storage device

If you get the same error even after complete format you better switch to a new storage device.

## update

unfortunately ntfs repair is not fully supported by any tool in linux. You can try `sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs` then
`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdaX`. The best way to fix ntfs is to check it from Windows. You can run chkdsk from any Windows repairCD/USB. [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1907603) ubuntu forum will help to create a  your own Windows repairCD.

Comment: it's not necessarly a hardware malfuction. It happens quite often on USB keys if you unplug it when you are `dd` something, for example. It could be a hardware fault, or simply an input/output error :)

Comment: @Parto. Solution to your problem given. What you now ask, file system repair, is almost impossible or risky from linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors is not a problem to delete files,
it's a problem about the file system himself and/or an hardware problem.

At this day, I don't know a good tool to check an Ntfs file system under Linux, there is "scrounge-ntfs" but for me: there is a lot of risk.

Backup immediately your files on another partition or on another device.

Then, if this is possible (if all necessary files was copied), you can delete the partition, make a new one with "fdisk" and "mkfs.ext4" for example,
and you can test the new partition by copying a lot of data on it.
If you have rapidly "Input/output error" again, then, you can consider the disk or the usb key as a dead device ...